# Email with SMTP from a VLAN

Tags: c#, smtp, smtpclient

I'm trying to send an automated email from my desktop application using Visual Studio C# and SMTP. It works when directly connected to the Wi-Fi but the moment I connect to the VLAN that we set up, the `SmtpClient.Send()` times out.

```
public static void SendEmail(string toAddress, string subject, string body)
{
    string senderID = "email";             
    const string senderPassword = "password";       
    try
    {
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient
        {
            Host = "smtp.gmail.com",                   
            Port = 587,
            EnableSsl = true,
            DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
            Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(senderID, senderPassword),
            Timeout = 30000,
        };
        if (IsValidEmail(toAddress))
        {
            MailMessage message = new MailMessage(senderID, toAddress, subject, body);
            smtp.Send(message);
        }
        else throw new Exception();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

We're using static IP, so I thought maybe it had something to do with DNS since the SMTP host isn't a specific IP.

Comment: Are you using gmail smtp in the real production code or you just replaced your exchange server adress for the sake of the sample ? that code works ont my side and is very similar to mine. So if you really use gmail it's probably the wifi connection that have different network rules than the VLAN. Otherwise if your are using your own exhange server, the server can have different sending routine depending on where the sender come from. Again that is a network issue.

Comment: @Franck. Thanks for your answer. I'm using the host given in the example. Would you suggest that I configure Microsoft Exchange on our server PC and route the emails from the VLAN networks to the server PC instead?

Comment: You need to talk to your network people and run some tests on the VLAN. Put a PC/server in the VLAN and see if you can ping the smtp server DNS name, if you can telnet to the server on the port you want to use, etc.

Comment: Does VLAN have an Outlook Email Server?  Most networks that have an Outlook Email server use a proxy server so you cannot directly connect to an outside email server without going through the proxy server.  There is a firewall that blocks the standard smtp port number.  The Outlook email uses port forwarding to get through the firewall.

Comment: @NetMage Yes, I'm going to run some tests tomorrow and see. Not sure how I haven't thought about pinging the SMTP dns. Thank you.

Comment: @jdweng I'm not sure. Could you enlighten me as to how I would determine whether or not it has an Outlook Email Server? I apologize, but I'm new with networking.

Comment: if your company has it own Domain : johnsmith@myCompany.com.  The email server is myCompany.  The comain name can be see from cmd.exe  
>set.  Even better if from cmd.exe >ipconfig/all which will give the dns server name.

Comment: @domin8 I am not suggesting that. It's really because if you use external SMTP then it has no ties to your network rules you use (wifi or vlan). It mean your problem is inside your network. If you would have had an exchange server it could have been issues on the exchange server configurations. So knowing it's gmail SMTP it is certain your issue is with the network, Could be trottling / traffic shaping / firewall rules specially for that port or simply based on your IP adress range. The way you describe i would be my hands that the Wifi and VLAN have different IP range. Wifi could be in DMZ.